# Same command, with different parameters, on a while true loop with bash or something else

Tags: bash

I always become crazy with bash, i don't understand it.
I basically want to do this (i'm not using some specific syntax, it's just to explain my problem):

```
processes_count = 20;

for (i = 0; i < processes_count; i++)
{
  php -f file.php "{$i}-{$processes_count}" &

  proc_id[i] = $!
}
```

The above cycle start the processes. The next one should keep the processes "alive for ever"!

```
while(true)
{
  foreach(proc_id as id)
  {

    if(!exist(proc_id[id]))
    {
         php -f file.php "{$id}-{$processes_count}" &

         proc_id[id] = $!
    }

  }
  sleep 5
}
```

If someone can help translating this into bash, python or something, thank you :)

Comment: How this connected to python?

Comment: i removed python. i've tried to do what you see above, without success :)

Comment: It's ugly, but it works :)



    processes_count=20;
    
    test=1;
    
    
    
    for ((i=1; i<=processes_count;i++))
    {
      php -f /w/web/back/download_gateway.php "{$i}-{$processes_count}" &
    
      proc_id[$i]=$!
    }
    
    while true;
    do
    
    for ((i=1; i<=processes_count;i++))
    {
    
    if [ ! -f "/proc/${proc_id[${i}]}/exe" ];
    then
    
    
    php -f /w/web/back/download_gateway.php "{$i}-{$processes_count}" &
    
    proc_id[$i]=$!
    
    
    
    fi
    
    }
    
    
    sleep 1
    
    done

Comment: @cedivad: Interesting and clever.  Well done.  (But ugly as sin!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that because `bash` doesn't provide a method to 'wait for any one child process to die and let me know which one it was that died'.  The nearest approach is `wait`:

> ```
> wait
> wait [jobspec or pid ...]
> ```
>
> Wait until the child process specified by each process id pid or job specification
>   jobspec exits and return the exit status of the last command waited for. If a
>   job spec is given, all processes in the job are waited for. If no arguments are
>   given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status
>   is zero. If neither jobspec nor pid specifies an active child process of the shell,
>   the return status is 127.

This means you can wait for a specific child to die, or you can wait for all children to die, but you can't do what you want.

If you drop into Perl or Python, you can do it, using the `wait` system call.